# Print matrix spirally from any point and using given direction

Tags: c++, matrix, spiral

How can we print given matrix spirally from any point and specified direction?

for example
if given matrix is

```
21  22  23  24  25  
20   7   8   9  10  
19   6   1   2  11  
18   5   4   3  12  
17  16  15  14  13
```

let current position be pointing to 1 and required direction is clockwise
*correct output* should be 1 2 3 4 5 6 .... upto 25.
I am looking for logic and code in C or C++

Comment: i have added more info please check

Comment: Could you please at least show some code for what you have already tried?

Comment: I thought a lot but couldn't approach any appropriate logic.

Comment: Just try, please. Showing your efforts, we can help you better, putting you on the right track.

Comment: What output should it provide if you start not from the center? P.S. I have an idea how to implement this.